# Need to return a dynamic set of columns from 2d array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I need to return several columns from an array pulled out of Google Sheets. Currently my code is

```
let out = data.map(function (row, index) { 
    return [row[1], row[0], row[36], row[6], row[45], row[46], row[47], row[7]]});
```

This code works well. But the needs have changed such that the report will have different columns each week. It will always have the columns I need, but the position of those columns will be changing. I can get the column numbers with

```
const colHeaders = ["Full Name","EID","Email - Work","Management Level"];
...
let sheetHeaders = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
let out = [];
for (let i in colHeaders){
 out.push(sheetHeaders.indexOf(colHeaders[i]));
}
```

but I don't know how to then use the list of header positions to return the full columns.

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced in the first code block. You have an extra `[` before each `row[N]`

Comment: Thanks, yes. That was an error of transcription here and not reflective of the actual script. The actual script was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the array of column numbers to the values in those columns.

```
let colnums = colHeaders.map(h => sheetHeaders.indexOf(h));
//...
let out = data.map((row, index) => colnums.map(col => row[col]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function gettingDataWithHeaderNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();//or whatever you wish
  const [hs,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const pos = hs.flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a.col[h] = i + 1; a.idx[h] = i; return a; }, {col:{},idx:{}});//idx returns index into array and col returns column number
  let out = vs.map(function (row, index) {
    return [row[pos.idx["COL2"]], row[pos.idx["COL1"]], row[pos.idx["COL10"]], row[pos.idx["COL7"]]]
  });
  //let end ="is near";
}
```

ActiveSheet Example:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 19 | 11 | 19 | 0 | 1 | 13 | 0 | 14 |
| 17 | 8 | 12 | 15 | 19 | 17 | 19 | 16 | 4 | 3 |
| 18 | 1 | 19 | 5 | 15 | 5 | 3 | 19 | 13 | 15 |

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)